# Is water with oxygen-17 safe to drink?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water, isotope

Is it safe to drink and what else can it be used for?

Comment: Since that isotope is stable, there would be no radiation danger. As @The_Vinz states, there would be no other practical biological difference.

Comment: Depends how much, I'd guess. Just like drinking $\ce{D2O}$, replacement of oxygen atoms in your body for heavier isotopes may lead to some metabolic reactions running slower than others, thus affecting metabolism. Of course, you'd need to replace most of the oxygen atoms contained in your body, which would require way too much $\ce{^{17}O}$ to see any noticeable effect.

Comment: It can be used to drain your bank account quickly...

Comment: The kinetic effect change would also not be as severe as in the case of $\ce{D2O}$.

Answer (score 1):

The isotope 17 of oxygen is NMR-Active, so it can be useful if isotopic labelling (eg: in the experimental study of a reaction mechanism) is needed.

Aside from that, since Oxygen-17 exists in nature, you are currently breathing it, and you do drink it.

Now, the question is: could we survive by breathing and drinking only Oxygen-17?

I don't think that anyone has ever answered that question, for economical reasons (from a fast search, a gram can be bought for around 500$!).

But, if I have to take a guess, I would say yes, since I don't think that the nuclear and mass properties of such an "heavy" atom would interfere with biochemical processes (unlike hydrogen's isotopes, the mass of oxygen and its isotopes is so large that they are not involved in quantum tunneling mechanism, and from this point of view their behaviour should be quite similar).